# Overloading << operator for std::ostream

Tags: c++, overloading

```
ostream& operator <<(ostream& osObject, const storageRentals& rentals)
{
    osObject << rentals.summaryReport();
    return osObject;
}
```

`summaryReport()` is a void function, and it is giving me an error:

> no operator "<<" matches these operands

but the error is not there if I change the `summaryReport` function to an `int`, but the problem I have with that is you have to return a value, and it is printing it out on the screen.

```
void storageRentals::summaryReport() const
{
   for (int count = 0; count < 8; count++)
      cout << "Unit: " << count + 1 << "    " << stoUnits[count] << endl;
}
```

Is there any way to overload `cout <<` with a void function?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should define `summartReport` taking `ostream&` as parameter, as shown here:

```
std::ostream&  storageRentals::summaryReport(std::ostream & out) const
{
    //use out instead of cout
    for (int count = 0; count < 8; count++)
        out << "Unit: " << count + 1 << "    " << stoUnits[count] << endl;

    return out; //return so that op<< can be just one line!
}
```

then call it as:

```
ostream& operator <<(ostream& osObject, const storageRentals& rentals)
{
    return rentals.summaryReport(osObject); //just one line!
}
```

By the way, it is not called *"overloading cout"*. You should say, *"overloading `operator<<` for `std::ostream`*.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things you need to do here. Make `storageRentals::summaryReport()` take an `std::ostream&` (you can *default* this to `std::cout`):

```
void storageRentals::summaryReport(std::ostream& os) const
{
    for (int count = 0; count < 8; count++)
    {
        os << "Unit: " << count + 1 << "    " << stoUnits[count] << endl;
    }
}
```

Then call it thus:

```
ostream& operator <<(ostream& osObject, const storageRentals& rentals)
{
    rentals.summaryReport(osObject);
    return osObject;
}
```

---

Note: An advantage of making `storageRentals::summaryReport()` take an `std::ostream&` is that you can pass it an `std::ostringstream` in your unit-tests and assert that it is providing correct output.

Answer (score 0):

If you overload `cout`, you may make some other place using `code` hard to understand, or more confusing. In fact, you could make your own class to complete the work. e.g. make a class `class MyPring`, and overload its `operator <<`.

Answer (score 0):

Your storage report implicitely is always streamed to cout. 
Imagine someone calling your function this way and having the rentals on cout instead of the file.

```
fstream fs("out.txt");
storageRentals rentals;
fs << rentals;
```

Why don't you stream your class like this:

```
ostream& operator <<(ostream& osObject, const storageRentals& rentals)
{

  for (int count = 0; count < 8; count++) {
      osObject << "Unit: " << count + 1 << "    " << rentals.stoUnits[count] << endl;
  }
  return osObject;
}
```

If the stoUnits member is private you need to make the stream function a friend of your storage class.

```
friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& osObject, const storageRentals& rentals);
```