# Overriding extraction operator for a expected format

Tags: c++

I want to override my extraction operator for `MyClass`, which has three `int` attributes, the first one has no more than three digits, the second one two and the last one.

The input has to be strictly like this: `123-45-6789`, if one of the parts has less digits than the maximum, the user must enter extra `0`s, like `001-02-3456`.

How should I make this? Should I read each letter as a `char` and then create the three `int`s? What would be the best way to create an `int` given a number of `char`s?

Comment: This is a bit broad, you essentially have to take a string as input and then validate it, you'd have to ensure that there were valid characters, 2 `-` separators, then attempt to convert the characters to an int and then pad with leading zeroes

Comment: I would use [Boost.Spirit](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/index.html) but it's certainly an overkill :)

Comment: Just learn how to pad [leading zeroes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1714515/how-can-i-pad-an-int-with-leading-zeros-when-using-cout-operator) and [overload << operator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10291385/overloading-operator-for-stdostream).

Comment: I think I wasn't clear about the zeroes. The user has to enter leading zeroes but then each part of the input "code" goes to an int.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like that:

```
MyClass{
    int a,b,c;
    MyClass(const char * str)
    {
        a = b = c = 0; 
        while(*str!='-')
        {
            if(*str<'0' or *str>'9')
            {
                throw std::std::invalid_argument("");
            }
            else
            {
                a=a*10+(*str)-'0';
                ++str;
            }
        }
        while(*str!='-')
        {
            if(*str<'0' or *str>'9')
            {
                throw std::std::invalid_argument("");
            }
            else
            {
                b=b*10+(*str)-'0';
                ++str;
            }
        }
        while(*str!=0)
        {
            if(*str<'0' or *str>'9')
            {
                throw std::std::invalid_argument("");
            }
            else
            {
                c=c*10+(*str)-'0';
                ++str;
            }
        }
    }
};
```

or even simpler....